# no idea what is going on here, not breaking out of loops

Tags: python

```
while UI != 1 or UI != 2:
    UI = int(input("Pay as you go Sim or no SIM (1/2)"))
    if UI == 1:
        FullOrder[1] = 10
    elif UI == 2:
        FullOrder[1] = 11
    ordernumbers = 1
    x=0
    if UI >=0 and UI <3:
        while x <= ordernumbers:
            print("your order currently is: ",Description[FullOrder[x]])
            print("your order currently is: ",Price[FullOrder[x]])
            x=x+1
```

No idea what is going on here, it isn't breaking out of the validation loop. I used not statements

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Change or to and

Comment: Indent your code. All the lines following the while should be indented.

Answer (score 0):

You stay in the loop because this condition is always verified :

```
while UI != 1 or UI != 2:
```

Indeed, UI will always be different from 1 OR different from 2

You should do :

```
while UI != 1 and UI != 2:
```

which is equivalent to :

```
while not (UI == 1 or UI == 2):
```

Comment: Good old DeMorgan... `if UI not in (1, 2)` will make this much less "confusing"

Answer (score -2):

```
while UI == 1 or UI == 2:
```

try changing the while loop as above, use UI=1 to initialize the code